# awk on windows - print fields - quotes as delimiter

Tags: windows, awk, field, quotes, delimiter

this is the feed file,

```
dfscmd /map "\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Group Pension\Quality Assurance Auditors" "\\serverfile16\bugp-qaaud$" ""
dfscmd /map "\\SERVER24\dfs\userhome\serverfile52_d" "\\serverfile52\userhome_d" ""
dfscmd /map "\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Wealth Management\WM CSC Stats - Support Team, CRT Team & CSR Performance" "\\serverfile48\bucan-WM_CSC_Support_&_CRT_Team_Stats" ""
```

Using this line

```
gawk -v FS=""" "{print $2 \";\" $4 }" a.txt
```

I am able to print but I cannot save the output,

```
C:\>gawk -v FS=""" "{print $2 \";\" $4 }" a.txt   >b.txt
\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Group Pension\Quality Assurance Auditors;\\serverfile16\bugp-qaaud$
\\SERVER24\dfs\userhome\serverfile52_d;\\serverfile52\userhome_d
\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Wealth Management\WM CSC Stats - Support Team, CRT Team & CSR Performance;\\serverfile48\bucan-   WM_CSC_Support_&_CRT_Team_Stats
gawk: (FILENAME=a.txt FNR=3) fatal: cannot open file `>b.txt' for reading (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: seems like I found the solution 

 gawk -v FS=""" "{print $2 \";\" $4 }" a.txt   ">b.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes should always be used to surround `awk`'s braces. This would be better:

```
 gawk -v FS=\" '{ print $2 ";" $4 }' a.txt > b.txt
```

Contents of `b.txt`:

```
\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Group Pension\Quality Assurance Auditors;\\serverfile16\bugp-qaaud$
\\SERVER24\dfs\userhome\serverfile52_d;\\serverfile52\userhome_d
\\SERVER24\dfs\shared\can\Wealth Management\WM CSC Stats - Support Team, CRT Team & CSR Performance;\\serverfile48\bucan-WM_CSC_Support_&_CRT_Team_Stats
```

---

***EDIT:***

If you're using windows, you may also like to consider running a script like this:

```
gawk -f script.awk a.txt > b.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS="\"" }
{ print $2 ";" $4 }
```

This avoids having to wrap quotes around your expression and produces the results you require. HTH.

Comment: problem with that is that works for unix, but not for windows, but got it resolved, thanks

Comment: Ahh yes, I didn't see this tagged as a windows question.

Comment: @Eduardo: I've edited my answer. Although my experience with windows is limited, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -v FS=""" "{print $2 \";\" $4 }" a.txt   ">b.txt
```